# Can I point two separate ASP.NET websites to the same profile database?

Tags: .net, asp.net, profile, user-profile

I'd like two websites to have read/write access to the same user profile database (named "aspnetdb" by default). Presumably this is possible by configuring the websites appropriately in the web.config. Are there any issues I should be wary of?

Comment: I do not see any issues, but I did not have test it to give a 100% sure answer.

Comment: I can give a 100% affirmative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you may.

You need to ensure that each app has a common [machineKey](http://www.developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx) section in web.config so that cookies and other encryption is same for all.

Did you want both apps to use the same users/profiles? If so, you must ensure that the `applicationName` attribute in all of the provider sections is the same. Typically this value defaults to '/' so there should be no modifications necessary except for the common `machineKey` section.

If you wish to use the same database but wish to keep the membership separate, simply specify different `applicationName` attributes for each application.

So, yes, you may have multiple applications use the same database and/or same user data by appropriate configuration.

Comment: Great answer - I suspected the app name and machine key would come into it. Thanks.